# php - Improving zbar recognition of scanned qr codes

Tags: php, qr-code, imagick, zbar

I'm trying to read scanned qr codes from php, running zbarimg via exec. Working not-too-bad.

The issue is that it seems to choke on scanning artifacts like these small dots:
[image]

I've been trying to get rid of the `white dots syndrome` by fiddling around with Imagick - changing brightness/contrast/sharpness seems to make them stand out less but some, like this one, are still unreadable.

Is there a way to remove the white dots / improve zbarimg's recognition?

---

Edit:

One thing I forgot to point out:
What strikes me as weird is the fact that scanning the QR via smartphone, using the camera, reads the code succesfully in a single instant without a single issue, which leads me to think this "fixing up" shouldn't even be needed. 
Am I just using zbar the wrong way?
Or do mobile OSes just use a different, better, algorithm? I tried using a zxing wrapper for PHP as well, but it gave even less results compared to zbar.

Comment: With `L`ow error correcting as in this one more then 7% damage and it cant be read, someone should come up with a function/algo/filter which detects the 3 main fiducials and creates a grid, then runs over each block in the grid and fixes by the average coverage/color in that block. 6k repos on github for qrcode generators, 0 fixers...

Comment: The QR code is already good enough to read, your application just needs to  give it a gentle "nudge" by o-so-slightly bluring with `Imagick::blurImage`.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of cleaning up the image you have shown us, the obvious approach would be to use [cellular automata](http://www.ijcee.org/papers/820-IT150.pdf) - although for best results you would ant to modify the behaviour to encompass the sharpening and thresholding you are already applying using other filters. You might consider setting the size of the cell to, say, one 25th of the QR code block resolution rather than a 1:1 with pixels in the unerdlying image. Really you should be applying your thresholding via a histogram based approach (assuming that you can isolate the QR code in the image).

I'm not aware of an implementation in PHP but there is at least one [OpenCV interface for PHP](https://github.com/mgdm/OpenCV-for-PHP)

Comment: That's really useful info, thank you.
Like I said above, though, my smartphone has no issue reading the exact same qr which leads me to think I'm not using zbar the right way.